# Replace only certain percentage of value in condition

Tags: r

I would like to change 5% of the good data into outliers. So in this case n=40 which means I need to change 2 y-values to become outliers. But I dont know how to put in one more condition to let R know that I only want to change 2 y-values, instead of all values less than or equal to 2. Following are the R codes that I tried:

```
set.seed(1001)
x1 <- runif(40,1,10)
y1 <- 5 + x1
x <- 2
for (i in 1:length(x1)){
  if (x1[i] <= x){
    y1[i] <- rnorm(1,20,1)

  } 
}
```

Comment: Something like `y1[1:x] <- rnorm(x, 20, 1)` maybe?

Comment: Also `y1[sample(1:length(y1), x)] <- rnorm(x, 20, 1)` if the selection of `y1` values to be changed should be random as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the outliers to be randomly selected.

```
set.seed(1001)
x1 <- runif(40,1,10)
y1 <- 5 + x1

change_idx <- sample(1:40, 2, replace = FALSE)
y1[change_idx] <- rnorm(2, 20, 1)
```

The line `y1[change_idx]` makes use of vectorization, so there is no need for loops.

To make it easier to reuse it or change variables, you could use some variables for values that are used in the code:

```
n <- 40
o <- 2

x1 <- runif(n,1,10)
y1 <- 5 + x1

change_idx <- sample(1:n, o, replace = FALSE)
y1[change_idx] <- rnorm(o, 20, 1)
```

You can now visualise your data and mark the outliers:

```
group <- rep("normal", n)
group[change_idx] <- "outlier"
ggplot(data.frame(x1, y1, group)) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1, col = group))
```

[image]

Depending on what you want to achieve I recommend adding some noise to the `y1` variable, e.g. `y1 <- 5 + x1 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)`, which will result in data like this: [image]